# React error al actualizar un componente desmontado

Tags: reactjs, component, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Estoy creando un clon de [giphy](https://giphy.com) y por ende estoy usando su API.
El problema ocurre en la ruta de mi app `/gif/:id`. Los componentes que terminan en "Loading" son react placeholders.

Leí acerca del problema e **intente con AbortController, y ahora con useRef** para saber si está montado o no el componente.

**Lo que busco como resultado** es que al solicitar un gif en especifico, SimilarGifs carge automaticamente los gifs relacionados al mismo, y cuando seleccione otro gif, vuelva a recargarse el componente para volver a buscar gifs relacionados al gif actual

**El error** que obtengo es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**useGifsAPI** el encargado de ejecutar el servicio correspondiente al endpoint que quiera solicitar:

```
   export function useGifsAPI(service, options) {
  
      const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
      const [gifs, setGifs] = useState([])
  
      const isMounted = useRef(null)
  
      useEffect(() => {
 
          isMounted.current = true
 
          if (isMounted.current) {
              setLoading(true)
              service(options).then(data => {
                  setGifs(data)
                  setLoading(false)
              })
          }
 
          return () => isMounted.current = false
 
      }, [options])
 
      return { loading, gifs }
  }
```

**Componente GifQueried** que actúa como vista de la ruta `/gif/:id` :

```
 15 export default function GifQueried() { 
 16     const { id } = useParams()
 17
 18     const { loading, gifs } = useGifsAPI(getGifData, {id})
 19
 20     return (
 21         <div id="gif-queried" className="container">
 22             <div className="sub-container">
 23                 { !loading
 24                     ? <React.Fragment>
 25                         <OwnerProfile owner={gifs.user} source={gifs.source} />
 26                         <GifInfo url={gifs.images && gifs.images.downsized_large.url} title={gifs.title} />
 27                         <SimilarGifs similarTo={gifs.title} />
 28                     </React.Fragment>
 29                     : <React.Fragment>
 30                         <OwnerProfileLoading />
 31                         <GifInfoLoading />
 32                         <SimilarGifsLoading />
 33                     </React.Fragment>
 34                 }
 35             </div>
 36         </div>
 37     )
 38 }
```

(getGifsSearched es el servicio que hace la peticion a la api de giphy y me devuelve los registros, nada mas)
**Componente SimilarGifs** que recibe una prop la cual se usara para buscar gifs relacionados a la misma:

```
  7 export default function SimilarGifs({similarTo}) {
  8
  9     const { gifs } = useGifsAPI(getGifsSearched, {search: similarTo, page:0})
 10
 11     return (
 12         <div id="similar-gifs">
 13             { gifs.map(gif => <GifElement section="similar" gif={gif} key={gif.id} />) }
 14         </div>
 15     )
 16 }
```

Comment: ¿Estás usando `axios`? Si es así te recomiendo leer [este](https://since1979.dev/cancel-axios-request-to-prevent-react-from-yelling-at-you/) artículo, que habla de exactamente ese problema. Tal vez de igual manera te pueda ayudar a buscar una solución, yo tenía el mismo problema con un objeto tipo drawer que hacía un fetch.

Comment: No, estoy usando Fetch API, pero gracias por el aporte de todas formas.

Comment: Algo no tiene tiempo para actualizar. Has probado usar `console.log` para ver si el `similarTo` o el `gifs` actualizan tres veces?

Comment: Probe poniendo un console.log en donde recupera los gifs, y al parecer entra en un bucle haciendo fetch's infinitos a la api.

Comment: Entonces puedes usar `useEffect` para solo actualizar cuando similarTo cambia.